# C# foreach UserControl

Tags: c#, winforms, foreach, combobox, user-controls

I'm trying to evaluate a formula in C#, using this code:

```
foreach (ucBstelle b in ucAufnahme1.Controls)
{
    foreach(Control c in b.Controls)
    {
        TextBox txt = c as TextBox;

        if (txt != null)
        {
            if (txt.Text == "")
               txt.Text = "0";

            Match match = Regex.Match(txt.Text, "[0-9]");

            if (!match.Success)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please use only numbers");
                return;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

- `ucBstellen` is a user control with a combobox and 4 textboxes.
- `ucAufnahmen` is another user control containing 3 `ucBstellen` and some other controls (4 comboboxes, 2 textboxes and a button)

When I try to debug the code it throws an `InvalidCastException` that says:

> ComboBox can't be converted to ucBstelle

Can anybody tell me what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

change

```
foreach (ucBstelle b in ucAufnahme1.Controls)
```

to

```
foreach (ucBstelle b in ucAufnahme1.Controls.OfType<ucBstellen>())
```

you are getting error when `foreach` tries to cast comboBox from `Controls` collection

Comment: Also, the next loop can use `.OfType<TextBox>`

Comment: When I try this it says Foreach cannot operate on a 'method group'